# Tricky MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a very tricky mysql trigger - I have 3 tables, machine, parts, usedin...
machine has mname, price...
parts has pname, cost...
usedin is to store how many parts are used to build a machine, so there is mname, pname, amount (amount of parts used in a machine)

Now I need to make sure that machine price is always greater than the sum of cost of all the parts it's made of, using a trigger. In other words, every time I update a cost of a part, the price of the machines that have the updated part will be automatically calculated to be sum(cost*amount), if the price is lower than that. The trigger below is my first try.
Then I tried to replace set price = new.cost to

select sum(amount*cost) from .....

I found that I had a very hard time to set the price to sum(cost*amount) because once I find the updated parts, there are multiple machines use the parts, and same time they are using other parts, I had a hard time to sum them together and still set each machine to their respective sum. Do I need a loop here? how? I'm very new to mysql.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    create trigger setPrice after update on parts 
    for each row
    begin
    update machine m inner join usedin u inner join parts i
    set price = new.cost
    where price < new.cost*amount and c.cname = u.cname and u.iname = new.iname
    ;
    end//
```